# how to add heading in label, textinput and other widgets in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, title, textinput, heading

How to add heading/ title in kivy python. I am using TabbedPanel. Can anyone suggest me how to put title in Label, button, TextInput etc.. I want to put different title for different widget.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Each `TabbedPanelItem` has a text property which determines the heading. `Label` itself, `TextInput`, ... has no heading.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


kvstr = Builder.load_string("""
TabbedPanel:
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "first heading"
        BoxLayout:
            Label: 
                text:"I am the Label in the first Tab"
            Label: 
                text:"I am another Label in the first Tab"
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "second heading"
        Label:
            text:"I am the Label in the second Tab"
""")




class MyAppApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kvstr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppApp().run()
```

Comment: Suppose there are Label, TextInput, Button in a TabeedPanel. Is there any way to give heading in the Labels, TextInput, button ??

Comment: you can make some of the text in a label bold or put it together with another label in a BoxLayout. The concept of headings does not really make sense to me in kivy maybe explain more what you mean by that

Comment: BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text:"[b]Maybe I am a heading[/b]"
            Label: 
                text:"I am another Label in the first Tab" sth like this?

Comment: "ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists" this error is coming in "markup: True" line. Actually what is required is: to give heading for label, heading for TextInput, heading for Button like this..(the same process in all the TabbedPanel).